# Describe the set $|z^2| = \operatorname{Im}z$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a little question about the problem above. The provided solution is a circle centered at $\frac{1}{2}i$ with radius $\frac{1}{2}$. But isn't this saying that the radius of the circle must equal its imaginary part? So isn't this true for arbitrary circle centered at $ai$ with radius $a$? Or am I thinking about this wrong?

Comment: Let us denote $X$ the set of all complex numbers that obey this equation, this is the set we are looking for. You should not confuse the radius of the circle $X$, with the modolus (radius) of $z\in X$. I hope this clarify your confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** With $z=x+iy$:
$$|z^2|=|zz|=|z|.|z|=|z|^2=x^2+y^2=y$$

Comment: Doesn't this give a circle centered at the origin with radius $\sqrt{y}$? The solution given for the problem doesn't satisfy this?

Comment: $x^2+y^2-y+\frac14=\frac14$

Comment: Ah, of course! I mean the fact that it had to be a circle made sense, and I should've seen the relationship above. Thank you!

Comment: Your welcome!..

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to look at things:  The circle centered at $i\over2$ with radius $1\over2$ is given by the equation $|z-{i\over2}|^2={1\over4}$.  But

$$\begin{align}
\left|z-{i\over2}\right|^2={1\over4}
&\iff\left(z-{i\over2}\right)\overline{\left(z-{i\over2}\right)}={1\over4}\\
&\iff\left(z-{i\over2}\right)\left(\overline{z}+{i\over2}\right)={1\over4}\\
&\iff z\overline{z}+{i\over2}(z-\overline{z})+{1\over4}={1\over4}\\
&\iff z\overline{z}=\left(z-\overline{z}\over2i \right)\\
&\iff|z|^2=\operatorname{Im}z
\end{align}$$

Comment: This is also a really nice way to look at it! Thank you